# VB Script to Send Outlook Mail on Appointment to Group Doesn't Work When Group Name Has Space

Tags: vba, email, outlook, automation

I've got a script that automatically sends an email off to a list of people when an appointment reminder is triggered - that is as long as the appointment is within a specific category.

The script works perfectly fine when I create a new appointment, put it in the right category and then put as many email addresses as I want in the 'Location' line when creating a new appointment. I can even put in group names with no problem and the automailing script will toss out a mail to everyone in the group.

The problem is when I put group names with spaces in them. I can't figure this out at all, as it works perfectly fine when a single name has a space in it but when it's a group it breaks.

Here's the script;

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim objMsg As MailItem
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

If Item.Categories <> "AutoSendEmail" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

  Dim contactsFolder As Folder
  Set contactsFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)

'   Dim group As DistListItem
'   Set group = contactsFolder.Items("TestingAutomation @ Test")

  objMsg.To = Item.Location
  objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
  objMsg.Body = Item.Body
  objMsg.VotingOptions = "Yes;No"
  objMsg.Send

  Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT: Looks like it has nothing to do with having a space in the group name, it's because the group has other groups inside of it. Still trying to figure out how to get around that.**

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs on `MailItem.To`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860378.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> Remarks
>
> This property contains the display names only. The To property
>   corresponds to the MAPI property PidTagDisplayTo. **The [Recipients
>   collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751.aspx) should be used to modify this property.**

So I would suggest something along the lines of

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub
  If Item.Categories <> "AutoSendEmail" Then Exit Sub

  Dim names, name
  names = Split(Item.Location, ";")

  With Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    For Each name In names
      .Recipients.Add(name)
    Next
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .Subject = Item.Subject
    .Body = Item.Body
    .VotingOptions = "Yes;No"
    .Send
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I ran into the same error I was getting before and it made me think that it's probably not simply having a space in a group name.

Turns out it's because the group I'm sending it to also has multiple groups inside of it, which causes a 'Name not recognized' error when I try to send the mail, (it resolves just fine, but breaks when it hits the .Send line.)

Any ideas on how I'd be able to fix that?

Comment: Not unless you tell me what "breaks" means - which error is there? Apart from that, if it works in the Mails you create manually in the UI, it ought to work in the mails you create programmatically.

Comment: Of course, sorry, the error I'm getting is:
'Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) Outlook does not recognize one or more names.'
I've tried using the script to send to a group with 2 emails in it and it works. Then I tried to send to a group that contained 1 email and 1 group with an email in it and it gives me this error.

Comment: And when you do the same by hand, in a normal email, then it works? That's curious. I'm afraid I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Yup, it works fine when I send it out manually to a group that contains groups, (I sent it manually using the exact same recipients as the automated version.)

Comment: Looks like a red herring to me. Does it start to work in VBA when you remove the sub-group from the offending group?